# I want to sort css properties with python

Tags: python, regex

i want to sort css properties in html files with vim using python

I came with this solution:

```
!python -c "import sys,re;r=re.compile('class[=:]\s*\"(.*?)\"');i=sys.stdin.read();r=r.search(i);a=r.start()+7;b=r.end()-1; print(i[:a]+' '.join(sorted(i[a:b].split()))+i[b:], end='')"
```

which in more readable form looks like this:

```
import sys,re
r=re.compile('class[=:]\s*\"(.*?)\"')
i=sys.stdin.read()
r=r.search(i)
a=r.start()+7
b=r.end()-1
print(i[:a] + ' '.join(sorted(i[a:b].split())) + i[b:], end='')
```

And it works fine for html - my only problem is the `a+7 b-1` because python re module gives me the address of beginning and end of a match not the group. I want to do this more universal and use it also for ruby and elixir where instead of `class="` which is 7 letters I'll have `class: "` which is 8 but I'm not really sure how to do this without making the code much more complicated. I'm looking for suggestions

Comment: `r.groups()[0]` should give you value from first `( )` - so you get only names of classes. If you put `class[=:]\s*\` in separated `( )` - `(class[=:]\s*)\"(.*?)\"'` - then you should get it with `r.groups()[0]` and names with `r.groups()[1]`

Comment: Thank you - so basically I need to create 3 regexes - 1 for the beginning of line , 1 for the classes and one for the end of line

Comment: you can use one regex but with many `( )`  and every `( )` will catch different part - and you get these parts using `r.groups()`. Using `(class[=:]\s*)\"(.*?)\"'` you catch two parts - first `()` catches `class=` or `class:` which you get in `r.groups()[0]`, second `()` catches names of classes which you get in `r.groups()[1]`. If you need to get something more at the end then add `(.*)` at the end and you get it in `r.groups()[2]`. If you need get something before `class` then add `(.*)` before `class` but then indexes in `[ ]` will change.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation again-now I understand it